# Datagridview data populating on 1 machine but not another C# (Win Forms)

Tags: c#, sql, forms, datagridview, datetimepicker

I have 2 laptops that both have visual studios. I have the exact program on both computers and the Datagridview is only populating on one of them, when its the exact code on both computers. Datagridview is getting populated from SQL Server, which is being hosted on a sever. Both computers have Visual Studio. I am not getting any errors. Not sure if the code is wrong or not, but I'm really trying to understand why it would only be working on 1 computer if its the same code.

I'm trying to populate the datagridview and be able to select a date and it will only show data associated with that date.

This is the code - `cargoBoardDate` is a datetime picker:

```
    private void GetCargoBoard(string command)
    {
        var calander = cargoBoardDate.Value.ToShortDateString();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM CargoBoard WHERE DateID LIKE @DateID";

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateID", "%" + calander + "%");

            connection.Close();
            connection.Open();

            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            da.Dispose();
            dgvCargoBoard.DataSource = dt;
            connection.Close();
        }

        connection.Close();
    }

    private void CargoBoard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetCargoBoard("SELECT * FROM CargoBoard");
        HeaderDesign();
        hideColumn();
        RenameHeader();
        formSize();
    }
```

Also my connection string is being called from a class (below):

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Helper.conString("LoadPlanner"));
```

I have also tried having the parameter line as such:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateID", calander);
```

If someone could explain to me what is going on for it to work on 1 machine but not another with the exact code and a possible solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Check windows settings for date format. Or better use dates as date type, not strings both in  your DB and in yor app.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the date parameter by passing in the actual date? cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateID", cargoBoardDate.Value); No need to convert anything, just pass the date object.

Comment: @Serg In DB the DateID is set to DATE. Also have tried just passing cargoBoardDate.Value. Neither have been working.

Comment: @Slugsie I have tried that and nothing will populate like that. For some reason the code above will populate the datagridview the way it is, but on another computer it won't even with the exact same code and DB running.

Comment: You should never pass a date as a string it's bound to fail at some point when you run on a PC with a different date format. Have you tried changing your SQL to use '=' instead of 'LIKE' when you pass an actual date into the parameter?

Comment: @Slugsie Tried that and still not working. When doing that, it will not populate the datagridview. It populates on one computer once again but not on another.

Comment: Have you validated that you can actually get ANY data back from the DB sever on the second machine? On the second machine have you changed the query to grab all the records to validate that the problem is related to "that" particular query.

Comment: @Slugsie It is working now. Thank you so much !

Comment: @JohnG I will look into it if it causes problems again. Seems to be working now.